# How to create bar chart in ireport table?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to create a table which contains bar chart as a result of value of certain column value.
I have attached image. I want to show same output in report table.

Thanks..

[image]

Comment: I think a little more information might be helpful.  What is the source of your data?  Will it be a database?  Will you be using a SQL statement to pull the data into jasper?  Will you be using iReport to build the report?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I m fetching data from database. And using ireport to build it. I found the solution and I m going to post it as answer for this query.

Comment: Hey Dinesh, kindly post the answer if you have found one.! :)

Comment: @indyaah I have post the solution. Please follow the steps and let me know if you face any issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a chart follow the steps:

1) Add new stacked chart in a report.
2) Uncheck all BarPlot properties.
3) Uncheck Show Legend from Common Chart Properties.
4) Keep Orientation as Horizontal from Common Chart Properties.
5) Do right click on chart and select padding and border. Change the Value of cell padding as per your need.

Follow the above steps and let me know if there is any difficulty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a clear solution for your question's stylized table. You did remove label on your charts and add some padding. But that's not possible for displaying the bar and column together.